# racket - algorithm to cut din Ax

Tags: algorithm, racket

I´m developing a mini-game where I need to find out how many lines I can paint in a DIN-A0 paper if I get a DIN-Ax as input . For example:

```
;car horizontal and cdr vertical lines
(define A1 (list 0 1))
(define A2 (list 1 1))
(define A3 (list 1 3))
(define A4 (list 3 3))
(define A5 (list 3 7))
(define A6 (list 7 7))
(define A7 (list 7 15))
(define A8 (list 15 15))
(define A9 (list 15 31))
(define A10(list 31 31))
```

If I input an A1 I can paint 0 horizontal lines and 1 vertical and so on. I calculated them by hand but I wonder if there´s a more elegant algorithm to automatically get it because I´m not able to develop one. Here is more info about the DIn:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_216

Thanks

EDIT: This ilustrates what I mean.

http://www.prepressure.com/library/paper-size/din-a4

With A1 you can paint (0 1) meaning 1 vertical line.
With A2 you can paint (1 1) meaning 1 horizontal and 1 vertical line because there are four A2s in a A0 sheet. And so on with A3 (1 3)...

EDIT: Almost done, I just need to figure out how to deal with the first iteration since If I write (get-cuts 1 0 0 0) I get the DIN Ax-1 cuts. I´ll work it out when I have more time.

```
(define (get-cuts DIN-A count vl hl)
  (cond 
    ((= DIN-A count) (list vl hl))
    ((not(= (modulo count 2) 0)) (get-cuts DIN-A (+ count 1) hl (+(* hl 2) 1))) ; DIN-A impares
    ((= (modulo count 2) 0) (get-cuts DIN-A (+ count 1) hl hl )) ; DIN-A pares
  )
)
```

Comment: When you say 'and so on' I understand that in A2 you can paint 1 horizontal line and 2 vertical, however in the code you've given you define A2 as `(1 1)`. Which one is incorrect?

Comment: Sorry I meant and so on as in the list of A1 A2....in an A0 you can fit 4 A2s that´s why it´s 1 1.

Comment: What do you mean by horizontal / vertical lines? Can you put a picture of how 'painting' a line would look like? Just as example... We need more information about your problem, try to explain yourself a bit more.

Comment: Added a website where there´s an illustration. Hope it´s clear now

Comment: If you keep dividing each new section in half you have unlimited lines. How far down the rabbit hole do you want to go?

Comment: Since the ratio is sqrt(2) you get a An+1 from an An by folding it horizontally and turing it 90 degrees. If you don't turn it you'll just see it alternates between horizontal and vertical fold lines. An A10 has 10 folds, 5 horizontal and 5 vertical. Don't know where you get 31 from.

Comment: A10 is the maximum of the ISO 216 standard, that´s the limit. If you take an A0 (841 × 1189) and get an A10 (26 × 37) as input, you can draw 31 lines in each direction. I did it in a paper and that´s what I got. I think it´s correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wanted was an algorithm, so I made one:

Suppose that you have that for A0 you can draw **0** horizontal lines (Which we'll call  `A0.hl`) and **0** vertical lines (that we'll call `A0.vl`).

Then for A1 you can draw `A0.vl` and `(A0.vl*2)+1` horizontal and vertical lines respectively.

Analogously for A2 you can draw `A1.vl` (Number of vertical lines for A1) horizontal lines and the exact same number of vertical lines (this because we're examining a pair number [2]).

Thus, for any *x>1*, with `x%2 != 0`: for A*x* you can draw A*x-1*.vl horizontal lines and `(A*x-2.vl* * 2) + 1` vertical lines.

ANd for any *x>1*, with `x%2 == 0`: for A*x* you can draw A*x-1*.vl horizontal lines and A*x-1*.vl vertical lines.

You can do this with tail recursion; maybe keeping the number of horizontal and vertical lines for pair numbers and odd numbers (4 variables), but perhaps there's an easy way without having to keep all these variables. I'd give it more thought but I gotta go now.

Hope this helps you get a better idea!

Let us know of any doubt ;)

Comment: Don't worry, remember to mark it as an answer if it solved your problem!